AppwriteException: User (role: guests) missing scope (account)
This are my Create, SaveUser, signIn and signOut functions to log or create a new user.
Whenever I am logged in and try to logout, it logs in some error in console:

AppwriteException: User (role: guests) missing scope (account)
at Client.

Also when I am logged in and refresh the page it get redirect to login page again when I am logging in, it shows too many sessions are running.
This is my code:
export const createUserAccount = async (user) => {
  try {
    const newAccount = await account.create(
      ID.unique(),
      user.email,
      user.password,
      user.name
    );
    if (!newAccount) throw Error;

    const avatarUrl = avatars.getInitials(user.name);

    const newUser = await saveUserToDB({
      accountId: newAccount.$id,
      name: newAccount.name,
      email: newAccount.email,
      username: user.username,
      imageUrl: avatarUrl,
    });
    console.log(newUser);
    return newUser;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};

export const saveUserToDB = async (user) => {
  try {
    const newUser = await databases.createDocument(
      appwriteConfig.databaseId,
      appwriteConfig.userCollectionId,
      ID.unique(),
      user
    );
    return newUser;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export const signInAccount = async (user) => {
  try {
    const session = await account.createEmailPasswordSession(
      user.email,
      user.password
    );
    let accountDetails = await account.get();
    store.dispatch(login({ userData: accountDetails }));
    console.log(accountDetails);
    return session;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export const getCurrentUser = async () => {
  try {
    return await account.get();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export const signOutAccount = async () => {
  try {
    const session = await account.deleteSessions();
    return session;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};


and here is my logout btn code:
const handleLogout = async () => {
    try {
      const session = await account.deleteSessions();
      console.log("Logout is Clicked");
      navigate("/login");
      return session;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

